# Why are Selenium searches delay compared to The Human Hand ( Manual search )

Tags: php, search, selenium, delay

I'm using the facebook webdriver with PHP Unit.

Whenever I enter 'PHP Unit' manually in a search field. It finds it instantly(within a second).
The code below is what I use to send 'PHP Unit' into the searchbox and the code works just fine.
Just whenever selenium enters the text into the searchbox, it takes about 8-13 seconds before it finds a result/starts searching.

**Question:** Any clue why this happens and is it normal or can I bypass this issue somehow?

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="datatable_modules_wrapper"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tfoot/tr/td[1]/div/input'))->click();
sleep(1);
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('PHP Unit');
```

**EDIT:** The searchbox has live filtering so when I start typing it searches instantly.
When I enter the text with selenium, it pastes it all in at the same time basically, could this be an side-effect of it?

Comment: This is not inherently a Selenium issue. I've just tested some live filtering function I have in one of my projects. It does not matter one bit whether I enter the text letter-by-letter, or if I cut and paste it into the field (which fills the field in one shot) or if I have Selenium fill the field. So the issue is with how your search function operates, **or** there is something else (not shown in your question) you are doing in your Selenium code that affects what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is pointing to your issue.  Here is the logic and execution.

**Manual**:
 1. Type some text
 2. javascript is executed on text change which filters results.  The time to enter the key and see results should be minimal but the performance decreases because it is already filtered for each letter. Thus subsequent letters entered take less time to visually see than before.

**Automated**:
 1. All letters are suddenly existing in the search.  The filter will have to process all letters at the same time resulting in a longer javascript filter time than if there was one at a time. (shouldn't be that much longer though)

The overall time should be shorter for the automated test even though the "appearance" of the filter should be shorter.  So if you time your manual entry to completed rendering and then time your automated entry to completed rendering the automation time should be faster overall.

If this is not the case in your situation which points to an application problem in the processing of that control.  The javascript filter execution is not being fired the same way.  You might try a manual copy and paste and compare this as the events might actually be different javascript events to execute the filter.  If the manual copy and paste doesn't match the same behavior then I suggest trying to send individual key strokes and not use the built in sendkeys functionality.  The sendkeys will be closer to a copy & paste than an actual typing of the keyboard.

I know how to do this in other languages, but I don't think php has built out as much support for this as other languages.  pear.php.net seems to have a little support of this type of functionality that would send hardware keystrokes and not just modify the DOM with text on the control.